# Is it okay to submit a modified journal paper that is still under review to a conference?

Tags: journals, ethics, conference, paper-submission

I have a paper submitted to a journal that is currently under review.

My research supervisor now wants to then submit a similar paper to an upcoming conference, by taking an older version of this same paper, and removing some content to fit the conference page limits.

I would understand the conference paper to make sense for a work-in-progress, to have been submitted at an earlier time before a submission to a journal for review, but the work has already been completed.

Would there a possible ethical problem with submitting a purposefully stripped-down version of a work to a conference, after a journal submission had already made?

Comment: You would probably violate the journal's policy.  Usually, you are required to declare that the work has not been submitted/published anywhere else.  If it has, then you need to note the differences.

Comment: Following from @Prof.SantaClaus, you might also violate the conference's policy: The same rules apply.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Prof.SantaClaus and user2768. Due to policy conflicts, no paper was submitted to the conference.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I suggest you make that a formal answer since it seems like it would be accepted. It seems odd to have no answer but the resolution strictly in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From two responses in the comments, submitting to a conference after a submission to  a journal would likely have policy violations from both the journal and the conference.

(#1)

> You would probably violate the journal's policy. Usually, you are
>   required to declare that the work has not been submitted/published
>   anywhere else. If it has, then you need to note the differences.

(#2)

> you might also violate the conference's policy: The same rules apply.